# How to disable the button

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Hi I want to disable the button. in the code where I had written  part there I'am trying to disable the button.In java script I didn't write any logic ..check attribute there i used disable functionality logic.

```
<aura:component controller="AlloactionController" implements="force:appHostable,force:lightningQuickAction,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="isdisplay" type="boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="emplst" type="Employee__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="name" type="string"/>
<aura:attribute name="disabled" type="boolean" default="false" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
    <thead>
        <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
            <th  scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate"> employee Name</div></th>
            <th  scope="col"> <div class="slds-truncate">employee Id</div></th>
            <th  scope="col"> <div class="slds-truncate">FBP allocation</div></th>
            <th  scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate">TotalFBPallocation</div></th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.emplst}" var="emp">

            <tr>
                <td  class="cell">  <p>
                    {!emp.Name}
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td  class="cell">  <p>
                    {!emp.Id}
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td  class="cell"><p>
                    {!emp.FBP_Allocation_Limit_per_Year__c}
                    </p></td>
                <td  class="cell"><p>
                    {!emp.Total_FBP_Allocations_This_Year__c}
                    </p>
                </td>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!(emp.FBP_Allocation_Limit_per_Year__c> emp.Total_FBP_Allocations_This_Year__c)}">
                    <td  class="cell"> <p><lightning:button variant="brand" label="FBP Allocation" onclick="{!c.VfpageCall}" name="{!emp.Id}"  /></p></td>
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                        <td  class="cell"> <p><lightning:button  class="btnCls" variant="brand" disabled="{!v.disabled}" label="FBP Allocation"/></p></td>
                    </aura:set> 
                </aura:if>

            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is the button always enabled or disabled?

Comment: no..no..that button always has to be disabled...

Comment: Then why are you adding that button on UI? Or you still want to add that button and want it disabled always, try this `<lightning:button  class="btnCls" variant="brand" disabled="true" label="FBP Allocation" />` no need to use any variable.

Comment: thank you @its works for me...I used the variable but that time i didnt work ..why whats the reason?

Comment: i Added that button for client understanding In ui only he comes to know right ..just for his reference tats it

Comment: If the issue is resolved please post that as answer and close this thread.

Comment: Hi @itzmukeshy7...please post the answer..ill make it as best answer..we shall close this thread

Comment: @user44385 Done check the answer.

Comment: It did not disable because you had the disabled property set to an attribute and the default value of the attribute was false. Had the default value been true it would have worked they was you originally set it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make the button always hidden then why are you adding that button on UI? Or you still want to add that button and want it disabled always, try this:

```
 <lightning:button class="btnCls" variant="brand" disabled="true" label="FBP Allocation" />
```

no need to use any variable and if you want to use variable then set the default value to true:

```
<aura:attribute name="isDisabled" type="Boolean" default="true" />
<!-- More code if any -->
<lightning:button class="btnCls" variant="brand" disabled="{!v.isDisabled}" label="FBP Allocation" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **disabled="true"**.
So the button becomes as follows :

```
<lightning:button  class="btnCls" variant="brand" disabled="true" label="FBP Allocation"/>
```